# Как найти аннотации у метода аннотированного @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, асинхронность, аннотации

Есть локальная задача- найти методы с кастомной аннотацией, суть ее в маркере. То есть если эта аннотация имеется над методом, то название метода сохраняется для последующей работы с ним. Задача легко решается перебором бинов в ApplicationContext и методов у них, с поиском нужной аннотации у метода. Но как только у нужного метода имеется аннотация @Async, то isAnnotationPresent показывает, что такой аннотации нет, да и вообще у метода нет никаких аннотаций, в том числе и @Async. Всё еще интереснее, если в классе несколько методов с искомой аннотацией, и у одного из методов этого класса есть аннотация @Async, то описанный выше способ поиска аннотаций, показывает их отсутствие даже у методов которые @Async не отмечены. Вопрос, как можно найти все методы с нужной аннотацией в проекте?

Экспериментальный класс поиска Аннотации:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@EnableAsync
public class BeanFinder {
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public BeanFinder(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void findBean() {
        log.info("find async");
        Arrays.stream(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()).
            forEach(x -> Arrays.stream(applicationContext.getBean(x).getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(y -> y.isAnnotationPresent(Annotation1.class)).forEach(y -> log.info(y.getName())));
    }
}
```

Экспериментальная аннотация:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Annotation1 {
}
```

Экспериментальный класс с методами:

```
@Component
public class BeanAsync {
    @Async
    @Annotation1
    public void method1Async() {
    }
    @Annotation1
    public void method2() {
    }
    public void method3() {
    }
    @Async
    public void method4() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что для реализации асинхронного выполнения Spring оборачивает бин в прокси-объект (собственно, аналогично тому, как Hibernate поступает с lazy-полями).

У прокси-класса, естественно, нет указанных вами аннттаций, поэтому нужно достучаться до исходного класса, в чём поможет [ClassUtils.getUserClass()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#getUserClass-java.lang.Class-)

Итого, немного видоизменив, метод findBean() может выглядеть так:

```java
public void findBean() {
        log.info("find async");
        Arrays.stream(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()).
                map(s -> ClassUtils.getUserClass(applicationContext.getBean(s)))
                .flatMap(aClass -> Arrays.stream(aClass.getDeclaredMethods()))
                .filter(method -> method.isAnnotationPresent(Annotation1.class))
                .forEach(method -> log.info(method.getName()));
    }
```

Вывод в лог:

```
find async
method2
method1Async
```

P.S. следствие того, что асинхронное выполнение обеспечивается прокси-объектом: нельзя вызвать асинхронный метод из других методов того же объекта, т.к. вызов пойдет минуя прокси-обёртку.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Прям помогли.